# HTTPS Support for Lynx in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, ssl, https, lynx

I just downloaded and installed `Lynx` for Windows and It does not support HTTPS to browse most of the websites today, especially Wikipedia.

I download it from [Invisible Island](http://invisible-island.net/lynx/), I guess it's the official site for the application

I've also read that some users  modify configuration files and build it with SSL enabled in Linux.

The Windows version doesn't offer such support configuration during the setup.

[image]

How can I enable SSL or add the HTTPS support to Lynx in Windows?

Comment: You would have to add HTTPS support to it.  With that said since software recommendations are not on topic here at Superuser, its not possible for us, to make suggestions of alternatives.

Comment: How to add the HTTPS support to it?

Comment: You would have to modify the source of the program

Comment: Use cygwin lynx

Answer (score 1):

At [Invisible Island](http://invisible-island.net/lynx/#installers), you can download "Latest built with curses (not color-style)" and it mostly works. It doesn't seem to have access to the correct certificate info so I had to set FORCE_SSL_PROMPT:YES in the .cfg file so I'm not prompted with errors. (Well, it shows you errors but you don't have to do anything about them.)

Answer (score 0):

#### How can I enable SSL or add the HTTPS support to Lynx in Windows?

Use the [Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) version of [lynx](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-grep.cgi?grep=lynx&arch=x86_64).

It has SSL already compiled in and can browse https pages.

```
$ lynx --version
Lynx Version 2.8.7rel.1 (05 Jul 2009)
libwww-FM 2.14, SSL-MM 1.4.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2h, ncurses 6.0.20160423(wide)
Built on cygwin Apr 10 2013 12:32:36

$ lynx https://superuser.com/questions
```

[image]

Comment: Sadly the page to download doesn't seem to function [Internal Server Error](https://cygwin.com/cgi-bin2/package-cat.cgi?file=x86_64%2Flynx%2Flynx-2.8.7-2&grep=lynx)

Comment: @Chinggis6 Only the package search page is broken. Download and install cygwin from this page [Installing and Updating Cygwin Packages](https://cygwin.com/install.html). Make sure you select the lynx package when installing.

Comment: Yeah, but I'd like to install just `Lynx` without having to install the whole `Cygwin`, but thanks I didn't know it is included in Cygwin, I'll try it through Cygwin now